# Pass the value of a .csv file to a struct vector

Tags: c, file, csv, struct

I have my struct, and I have a vector of that struct. Also, I have a *.csv* file with data separated by comma.

What I need to do is take each value of every line of the .csv file and throw it into my struct vectors. Each line corresponds to a different vector index.

**File.csv model**

```
1,carlos,1232
321,patricia,212
5,james riko,23432
```

The quantity of fields in the same lane may vary, but it will always be separted by comma only.

I did something using `strtok()` but I couldn't find a way to fill the struct with that.

My Code:

```
typedef struct{
 int num_acc;
 char name[25];
 double value;
}struct_acc;  

int main(){

 FILE *arq_acc;
 struct_acc acc[3];
 char buffer[256];
 char *pointer;

arq_acc = fopen("accs.csv", "r");
if(arq_acc == NULL){
 printf("Error"); exit(0);}

while(pointer = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), arq_acc) ){
 char *token;

 while( (token = strtok(pointer, ",") != NULL){

  //Then I don't know how to fill the struct vector.
}
return 0;
}
```

I just pasted my old code to show you that I'm actually trying to do something.
I couldn't find a way to do what I need with this code, so I can get total differente code ideas to reach my goal.

In the old code, I need to restart the loop to change to the next value of the currently lane, then I can't add something like this:

```
while( (token = strtok(pointer, ",") ) != NULL ){
 acc[0].num_acc = token;
 // Now I need to set pointer as NULL and read the token again, to get the next value of the first row. But I can't do it like this. ;\
}
```

Comment: You first need to use `strtok` to get each line before getting each comma-separated value.

Comment: If there's always three columns in the csv you could do it like in this example: http://pastebin.com/MdsJHSnK (I'm too tired to write up a good answer - hence the pastebin ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data in the file are uniform, you can use `sscanf`. Keep track of an index that indicates which account from the array to fill.

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d,%24[^,],%lf",
               &(acc[index].num_acc),
               acc[index].name,
               &(acc[index].value));
```